# Multiple CSS style for the same template

Tags: css, meteor

I have to make a user interface that can be run in dark or sunny places. So, I want to make a "high contrast" theme and a "normal theme".

I understood that Meteor merges and minify all CSS files in one big stylesheet. So... I wonder how to switch between two theme, I can't use tricks like [this site](http://alistapart.com/article/alternate) explains.

I have thought of a solution : having super-class on the body, that contains only colors definitions, that I could switch with a little JavaScript. But that seems to be a little rude.

Any thought of a better solution ?

Comment: can't you use `Javascript` to de-load the old css file and load the new one and if you load a new css file it should overwrite the style of the current css file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `less` (an official meteor package), you can define two different classes that would be set on the body (or a main div), and give them all different styles:

```
.dark {
  p { color: #fff; }
  /* dark styles... */
}

.light {
  p { color: #000; }
  /* light styles... */
}
```

Then indeed, programmatically switch the class on the `<body>` or `<div>` tag, for example using `Template.registerHelper` and the `Session` class like @adnan-y suggested.

It would look cleaner (plus you could use tons of cool `less` features like `lighten` and `darken`), and everything will be compiled to css on server run.

Comment: I never used `less` before but I will look at this option. Anyway, I can do that without `less` isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, but with a lot uglier code. Basically you would have to add your body class before every rule declaration... or at least the color ones. Here, you just have two convenient namespaces with css in them. And basically, you don't need to write anymore `less` than what I wrote! You can put all regular css inside those classes, it will work flawlessly. Just name your file `style.less` instead of `style.css` and see for yourself. Then again, I understand if you still see this as adding complexity.

Comment: As I can see, my css declarations will be much more clear using `less` so I will totally use that ! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

write a helper such as

```
Template.registerHelper('theme', function(){
  // somehow get timeoftheday and return appropriate theme
  // alternatively get theme name from user.theme
  // here we are just getting it from session for now
  Session.get('theme');
});
```

in your layout template, set the root element class reactively:

```
<template name="layoutTemplate">
  <div class="content {{theme}}">
    {{> somenav}}
    {{> yield}}
    {{> footer}}
  </div>
</template>
```

css can be something along the line:

```
.dark {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  h1, h2, h3, .header, p {
  // some custom scheme related to dark scheme
  }
}
.light {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  p {
  // some custom scheme related to lightscheme
  }
}
.someotherthemename {
  background-color: pink;
  color: purple;
  p {
  // some custom scheme related to lightscheme
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the current syntax has changed to Template.registerHelper().

Comment: Damn ! I never knew there was a `registerHelper`, I feel so newbie... Thanks a lot, this solution is perfectly in the spirit of Meteor.

Comment: In fact... I can't reach the `body` tag using this solution. I have to use jQuery to manually change the `background-color` and it's much more code for the "same" result.

Comment: There is no need to style the body tag to change the theme. body should be limited to defining your base font, line height as such. Color should be applied to elements. underneath.